# Spring Security, JUnit: @WithUserDetails for user created in @Before

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security, mockmvc

In JUnit tests with Spring MockMVC, there are two methods for authenticating as a Spring Security user: `@WithMockUser` creates a dummy user with the provided credentials, `@WithUserDetails` takes a user's name and resolves it to the correct custom `UserDetails` implementation with a custom `UserDetailsService` (the `UserDetailsServiceImpl`).

In my case, the `UserDetailsService` loads an user from the database. The user I want to use was inserted in the `@Before` method of the test suite.

However, my `UserDetailsServiceImpl` does not find the user.

In my `@Before`, I insert the user like this:

```
User u = new User();
u.setEMail("test@test.de");
u = userRepository.save(u);
```

And in the `UserDetailsServiceImpl`:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = this.userRepository.findOneByEMail(username);

    if (user == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username));
    return user;
}
```

How can I use an account created in `@Before` with `@WithUserDetails`?

Comment: This StackOverflow answer is pretty much instructive : [Spring Test & Security: How to mock authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920932/2971820)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do easily `@WithUserDetails` with `@Before`, because Spring `@WithUserDetails` annotation will invoke Spring security context test listener before running `setUp` method with `@Before`.

Here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/38282258/1814524 a little trick and answer to your question.

Comment: Heads up: if you use transactions you will need to manually remove the content with `@AfterTransaction`. They are not rolled back automatically like with `@Before`.

Comment: 2021 UPDATE: With `setupBefore = TEST_EXECUTION` it works for me. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `@PostConstruct` instead of `@Before`. That did the trick for me. Can anybody confirm that?

Comment: This is working fine. Anyone knows any down side effects, none I see so far ... ?

Comment: @PostConstruct is the way to go, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

### Use `setupBefore = TEST_EXECUTION`

This will effectively cause `@WithUserDetails` to execute after `@Before` and `@BeforeEach`

```
@BeforeEach
public void createUser() {
   ...
}

@Test
@WithUserDetails(value = "username", setupBefore = TestExecutionEvent.TEST_EXECUTION)
public void expectToWork() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: cool, thx! this is the easiest way supporting transactions too!

Answer (score 6):

```
@Inject
private EntityManager em;

@Inject
PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

@BeforeTransaction
public void setup() {
    new TransactionTemplate(txManager).execute(status -> {

        User u = new User();
        u.setEMail("test@test.de");
        em.save(u);

        return null;
    });
}

@AfterTransaction
public void cleanup() {
    new TransactionTemplate(txManager).execute(status -> {
        // Check if the entity is managed by EntityManager.
        // If not, make it managed with merge() and remove it.
        em.remove(em.contains(u) ? user1 : em.merge(u));
        return null;
    });
}


@Test
@Transactional
@WithUserDetails(value = "test@test.de", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "loadUserByUsername")
public void test() {

}
```