# Understanding TestExecutionListeners and BaseTest class in SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, tdd, spring-test

I am trying to wire up few tests.
My doubt is regarding execution of Order of `TestExecutionListener` with parent class `@Before` and `@After` sequence of execution for currently running Test.

Example:

I have a class which setup some dummy user in table in test profile and deletes them. So i have created a base class for user related items.
My Base class is as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseDataTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private TestUserGenerator testUserGenerator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testUserGenerator = new TestUserGenerator(userRepository);
        testUserGenerator.createTestUsers();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        testUserGenerator.deleteTestUsers();
        testUserGenerator = null;
    }
}
```

I now have 2 scenarios:

1. Just insert user and later fetch from database that the count is more and users are present in test database.
2. I have to insert test users and later check for a particular user and fetch all the users from `blocked` table from current logged in user.

For scenario 1 which works fine since there is no `TestExecutionListener` annotation present on Test class so base class method setUp/cleanUp are called properly and my tests runs fine. My Test class is as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class UserInsertTest extends BaseDataTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @Test
    public void testThatSystemHasUsers() {
        Assert.assertNotSame(userRepository.count(), 0);
    }

}
```

For scenario 2 which is not working as becuase i have `TestExecutionListener` with `WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener` class as value, since my setUp method is not getting called and system has no users to prove authentication test is failing.
My BlockUserTest class is as below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestExecutionListeners(value = {WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class})
public class BlockUserTest extends BaseDataTest {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BlockService blockRepository;

    @Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "sabrinahuff@comstruct.com")
    public void blockNoneReturnEmpty() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
        List<Block> blockedByMe = blockRepository.getBlockedByMe(user.getId(), PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        Assert.assertNotNull(blockedByMe);
        //as i have not blocked anyone yet in test    
        Assert.assertSame(blockedByMe.size(), 0);
    }

}
```

I am getting

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create SecurityContext using @org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetails(value=sabrinahuff@comstruct.com, userDetailsServiceBeanName=, setupBefore=TEST_METHOD)

    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.createSecurityContext(WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.createTestSecurityContext(WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.java:123)
    ... 24 more


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pkg.BaseDataTest.cleanUp(BaseDataTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

2019-05-14 13:21:23.104  INFO 17612 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-14 13:21:23.108  INFO 17612 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-05-14 13:21:23.109  INFO 17612 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-05-14 13:21:23.112  INFO 17612 --- [       Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Which seems valid as inside principal is is null, because there are no test users present in db  and hence loadUserByUsername is returned with null value.

Method from `org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory`

```
public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithUserDetails withUser) {
        String beanName = withUser.userDetailsServiceBeanName();
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = this.findUserDetailsService(beanName);
        String username = withUser.value();
        Assert.hasLength(username, "value() must be non empty String");
        UserDetails principal = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, principal.getPassword(), principal.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        return context;
    }
```

Keeping `TestExecutionListener` and my test data generation how can i pass my block user test. Thank you!

Spring SecurityTest

```
@Test
    @WithUserDetails(value = "brysonhensley@yahoo.com")
    public void test() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
```

This seems to be working and upon debugging, my authentication object is populated with meaningful values, so `UserDetailsService` bean name is picked up i think so.

Comment: Execution of `@Before` and `@After` has nothing to do with presence (or absence) of `TestExecutionListener`s.  Also you don't need the specify it as the `WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener` will be automatically applied. Also please add the full stacktrace instead of only the, partial, message.

Comment: Ok, i have added full stacktrace, please take a look again.

Comment: You get a `NullPointerException`... probably originating from the fact you have a custom `UserDetailsService` with a different name.

Comment: `public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{}` is my userdetails service i have updated my other test for spring authentication in code please take a look.

Comment: Again, it does a lookup by name `userDetailsService` if you have registered it differently, the name is different and no `UserDetailsService` will be found and hence lead to a `NullPointerException` either force the name to be `userDetailsService` or add the proper name to the `@WithUserDetails .

Comment: I have added a test when authenticaion come true, can you please take a look again.

Comment: Again you get a `NullPointerException`, something is `null`that shouldn't be `null`. Maybe that user doesn't exist, or whatever. I cannot see or debug from here.

Comment: Finally you got, user is not in db, because setUp method is never invoked, hence coming to the question, does order matters here?

Comment: And again, executing the setup method is not related to `TestExecutionListener`s.

Comment: Ok, how can i prepopulate, database just before running security test such that userdetailservice would find users in database, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: May be i am running into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466954/spring-security-junit-withuserdetails-for-user-created-in-before

Comment: Rather this answer (linked from the one you added) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275420/issue-with-withuserdetails-and-spring-boot-1-4-testentitymanager/38282258#38282258 is the solution and apparently this specific one, executes before the `@Before` method (The answer is by the giuy who wrote/maintains the Spring Test stuff :) ). So apparently I was wrong, for this particulair `TestExecutionListener`.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not able to get it running :'(